# How I know from which country In App purchase has made?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I want to know the country name from where my application's in app purchase has buy.

Comment: On the device itself?  You don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

With the help of priceLocale you will get the currency type with the help of this you can check country name.